# SQL Linked Table Can Insert Can't Delete Run-Time 3086

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, execute

I use Access VBA to add and remove records in a single SQL table, which contains 2 columns of `varchar` codes. I am a `dbowner` on the SQL Server database. My code to add values to this table works:

```
For Each varItm In Me.lstMyAllTypes.ItemsSelected
            AddSQL = "INSERT INTO xyzMyTable ([MyCode1],[MyCode2]) " & _
                     "VALUES ('" & Me.lstMyAllTypes.Column(0, varItm) & "','" & Me.cboType.Column(1) & "');"
            'EXECUTE SQL
            CurrentDb.Execute AddSQL, dbSeeChanges
            'Debug.Print AddSQL
Next varItm
```

My delete code throws a run-time error 3086:

```
For Each varItm In Me.MylstTypes.ItemsSelected
    RemSQL = "DELETE FROM xyzMyTable " & _
              "WHERE xyzMyTable.MyCode1 = '" & Me.MylstTypes.Column(0, varItm) & _
              "' AND xyzMyTable.MyCode2 = '" & Me.cboType.Column(1) & "'"
            'EXECUTE SQL
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            CurrentDb.Execute RemSQL, dbSeeChanges
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Next varItm
```

I debug the delete SQL string and I can run it in SSMS, but not in Access. If I create the same delete query in an Access query, it does not work. If I open the table, and try to delete the row, it makes a ding noise, but there is no pop-up error. How can I add but not delete?

This table has no relationships in SQL Server to any other tables, so referential integrity would not be an issue.

Comment: If you switch your SQL to a SELECT does it retrieve any records?

Comment: Get the value of `RemSQL ` and run it in SSMS directly.

Comment: Does the SQL Server table have a primary key? -- Does Access recognize it (key icon in table design view)? -- What is the full error message?

Comment: I can obviously select, as I can add records, and I can open the table to attempt to delete one record manually. It just doesn't let me delete.  It's ok though, we are going a different way.

Comment: @Andre your comment was the answer. If you want to post that as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete or update in a linked ODBC table, the table needs to have a **Primary Key**.

The PK must be recognized by Access: open the linked table in design view, check there is a "lock" icon in the PK column(s).

Comment: I hadn't made the table, so I didn't even think to question this. I always put an identity column on tables, so I've never had this issue.  It's always the simple stuff that stumps you!